# R-Date and time analysis

Tags: r

I am working on a reservation/booking data analysis to identify most popular hours and least popular hours (staffing can be increased during peak hours and lowered during lull). I tried a `ggplot` of date and time, hoping to see a peak and lull. I got this error:

> ggplot(aes(x=dates, y=time),data=try)+geom_line error

Dont know how to add `geom_line` to this plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the `()` to make it work

```
  ggplot(aes(x=dates, y=time), data=try)+geom_line
  #Error: Don't know how to add geom_line to a plot
  ggplot(aes(x=dates, y=time), data=try)+geom_line()
```

#### data

```
  try <- data.frame(dates=1:5, time= sample(20, 5, replace=TRUE))
```